# argparse: dependency between multiple optional positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am looking for a way to parse the following commandline syntax using the argparse module in python3:

```
myapp.py [folder] [[from] to]
```

Meaning: The user may optionally define a folder, which defaults to cwd. Additionally the user may pass up to two integers. If only one number is given, it should be stored in the `to` variable. This is similar to the syntax of the python builtin `range()`.

e.g.:

```
myapp.py folder
myapp.py 10
myapp.py 5 10
myapp.py folder 5 10
myapp.py folder 10
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: How is argparse supposed to differentiate between `myapp folder` and `myapp 10`?  As far as I see it, you don't have much of a choice other than to post-process the returned namespace -- At which point, you might as well just process `sys.argv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also suggest parsing sys.argv yourself.

FWIW, I parse sys.argv even on projects where argparse or similar would work, because parsing sys.argv yourself plays nicely with pylint or flake8.

Answer (score 1):

Use options; that's what they're there for (and what `argparse` is good at parsing).

Thus, a syntax like

```
myapp.py [-F folder] [[from] to]
```

would make a lot more sense, and be easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something quite silly:

```
import argparse
import os

class MyAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        namespace.numbers = []
        namespace.path = os.getcwd()
        for v in values:
            if os.path.isdir(v):
                namespace.path = v
            else:
                try:
                    namespace.numbers.append(int(v))
                    if len(namespace.numbers) > 2
                       parser.error("Barg2!!!")
                except ValueError:
                    parser.error("Barg!!!")

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('stuff',nargs='*',action=MyAction)
n = p.parse_args()
print n
```

But if you're going to do this, you might as well just process `sys.argv` yourself -- you should really consider using actual options here...

Comment: holy sh** ... awesome answer, but I will follow your `sys.argv` advice

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see a way to do it without using a named argument for folder:

```
# usage: argparsetest2.py [-h] [--folder [FOLDER]] [to] [fr]

import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--folder', dest='folder', nargs='?', default=os.getcwd())
parser.add_argument('to', type=int, nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('fr', type=int, nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

Comment: that would be `[to] [from]`, not `[[from] to]`

Comment: @FabianHenze I think thats the only way to get the positional behavior you wanted.  If you revers the order, then a single integer gets assigned to 'from' instead of 'to'.  The only other option (for `argparse` anyway) is to use all named arguments, e.g `myapp.py --folder <folder>  -- from <from>  --to <to>`